# Handle typescript error when db is sending snakecase attributes and front accepts only pascalcase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I'm looking for the best practice to do a conversion when my api is sending me a snake case value and my front only accepts pascal case attributes.

Here is my problem :

**Front Request**

I have an axios request that gets multiple users. Let's say `axios.get('/users')`

**Api answer**

My api gives me a list of users :

```
[{
  id: 10
  last_name: 'Foo'
  first_name: 'Bar'
},{
  id: 11
  last_name: 'Baz'
  first_name: 'Bob'
}]
```

**Typescript User type**

Now I have a User type and my typescript only accepts pascal case attributes :

```
type User = {
    id: number,
    lastName: string,
    firstName: string
}
```

**Typing my axios response**

And now I'm passing the received users to an array `users` but the error occurs when I want to associate `lastName` with `last_name` and `firstName` with `first_name`.

```
let users: User[] = []

const res = await axios.get('/users')
res.data.forEach((user: User) => {
  users.push({
    id: user.id,
    lastName: user.last_name, // Typescript Error
    firstName: user.first_name // Typescript Error
  })
}

return users
```

Do anyone have a solution to this problème ? Do I need to tell my array that the user received by the api is of `any` type ? What is the best practice ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two approaches:

### Approach 1: Type the response from API differently

Because your response data has different keys, you can't really type it as `User`. You should have a separate type for it.

```
type UserData = {
    id: number,
    last_name: string,
    first_name: string
}
```

This would, of course, double the maintenance effort whenever you need to change some field's name and is more error-prone. However it is also more flexible.

### Approach 2: Convert response's field names before using it.

You can write a small utility that recursively converts field names from snake_case to camelCase. After that, you can type the response correctly as `User`. I use this approach personally and it works well, but typing the code is a little tricky. Below is the code I usually use, it might not be perfect and everyone is welcome to give feedback.

```
import { camelCase } from 'lodash-es';

export type JSONValue =
  | string
  | number
  | boolean
  | JSONValue[]
  | { [key: string]: JSONValue };

const recursivelyTransformKeys = (obj: JSONValue): JSONValue => {
  if (typeof obj !== 'object' || obj === null) {
    return obj;
  }

  if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
    return obj.map(recursivelyTransformKeys);
  }

  const result: JSONValue = {};
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    result[camelCase(k)] = recursivelyTransformKeys(v);
  });
  return result;
};
```

Then use it in your code like so:

```
const res = await axios.get('/users')
recursivelyTransformKeys(res.data).forEach((user: User) => {
  users.push(user);
}
```

Comment: I am trying the 2nd approach but when I'm trying to .forEach on my recursivelyTransformKeys(res.data), it says that Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'JSONValue' and Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'string'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Typescript to resolve above scenario then following way you can achieve it

```
interface user{
    id: number,
    lastName: string,
    firstName: string
}
interface userResponse{
    last_name: string,
    first_name: string
}
type User = userResponse | user;

const anExampleVariable: user = {
    id: 123,
    lastName: "123",
    firstName: "12"
}
```

Another way is to create helper function, then loop through response key and user helper function to transform keys from snack_case to pascalCase

Here is the Helper function

```
function pascalCase(val){
  const ary = val.split("_");
  return ary[0]+ary[1].charAt(0).toUpperCase()+ary[1].slice(1)
}
```